# How to print overflow header on second page

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to create a RDLC report, but I also need to produce this same report that will run in SSRS.

The page contains 2 lists, side-by-side. In most cases both lists will fit on one page, but if any of them overflow to the next page, then I want to print a header, showing "**Continued...**" and the page number (which is not the problem).

What is the best method to achieve this?  Will a rectanle allow me to print the header on the next page or should I use a different method?

Comment: YOu can write your edit as answer & accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, in case it can help someone else.

I added a Page Header and set the property PrintOnFirstPage to false. This allowed me to add the necessary "Continued ..." label to the page header, which will only print on the second page